# Why does this text "text 1" appended on the rectangular not render?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

So basically, i have checked that no error occurs in the console and the element tab in the dvelopper tools. I am just starting off with d3 (really beginner), but it feels like everything is fine with my code.

```
var h = 1000
var w = 1000

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("width", w)


var rect_ = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("class", "rect_class")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
d3.selectAll(".rect_class")
    .append("text")
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x")
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("y")
    })
    .text("text 1")
```

Comment: Essentially from the accepted answer: "_A rect can't contain a text element._"

Comment: ohh i see. Thank you for the immediate response.